# Dynamic Stack, stack_top in C

Tags: c, dynamic, stack, coredump

I've been practicing a bit using dynamic stacks, but i'm stucked at the point where when i try to print the content of all the stack i get core dumped.

### stack.c (pila.c)

```
void PILA_Crea(Pila *pP){ //stack create
(*pP) = NULL;
}

int PILA_Buida(Pila p){ //stack empty
    return (p == NULL);
}

int PILA_Plena(Pila p){ //stack full
    return 1;
}

int PILA_Top(Pila p){ //stack top
    if(p == NULL) {
        //ERROR (PILA BUIDA)
        return -1;
    }else{
        return (*p).element;
    }
}

void PILA_Push(Pila *pP, int element){ //stack push
    Node *pAux = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(pAux == NULL) {
        //Memoria KO
    }else{
        pAux->element = element;
        pAux->pSeguent = (*pP);
        (*pP) = pAux;
    }
}

void PILA_Pop(Pila *pP){ //stack pop
    Node *pAux;
    if(*pP == NULL){
        //ERROR (PILA BUIDA)
    }else{
        pAux = (*pP);
        (*pP) = pAux->pSeguent;
        free(pAux);
    }
}
void PILA_Destrueix(Pila *pP){ //stack free
    free(pP);
    (*pP) = NULL;
}
```

### stack.h (pila.h)

```
typedef struct sNode{
    int element;
    struct sNode *pSeguent;
}Node;
//PILA
typedef Node * Pila;

void PILA_Crea(Pila *pP);

void PILA_Push(Pila *pP,int element);

int PILA_Top(Pila p);

int PILA_Plena(Pila p);

int PILA_Buida(Pila p);

void PILA_Pop(Pila *p);

void PILA_Destrueix(Pila *pP);

#endif
```

The use of PILA_Top() in

### main.c

```
    while(!flag){
        if(!PILA_Buida(p)){
            cont++;
            printf("%d\n ",PILA_Top(p));
            printf("%d-",cont);
            PILA_Pop(&p);
        }else{
            flag=1;
        }
    }
```

and the error i get

```
    ...
    50-9
    51-11
    52-1936285535
    *** glibc detected *** prac3: free(): invalid pointer: 0x080482d2 ***
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6b161)[0xb76ec161]
    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6c9b8)[0xb76ed9b8]
    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb76f0a9d]
    prac3[0x8048c89]
    prac3[0x8048830]
    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0xb7697bd6]
    prac3[0x8048531]
    ======= Memory map: ========
    08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 00:17 1318400                        /users/home/alumnes/LS/ls28996/Apuntes/Laboratorio/Practica_3/prac3
08049000-0804a000 rw-p 00001000 00:17 1318400    /users/home/alumnes/LS/ls28996/Apuntes/Laboratorio/Practica_3/prac3
08bee000-08c0f000 rw-p 08bee000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7500000-b7521000 rw-p b7500000 00:00 0
b7521000-b7600000 ---p b7521000 00:00 0
b766c000-b7679000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 757409     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7679000-b767a000 r--p 0000c000 08:01 757409     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b767a000-b767b000 rw-p 0000d000 08:01 757409     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7680000-b7681000 rw-p b7680000 00:00 0
b7681000-b77d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 757562     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
b77d4000-b77d6000 r--p 00153000 08:01 757562     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
b77d6000-b77d7000 rw-p 00155000 08:01 757562     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
b77d7000-b77da000 rw-p b77d7000 00:00 0
b77dd000-b77e1000 rw-p b77dd000 00:00 0
b77e1000-b77e2000 r-xp b77e1000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b77e2000-b77fd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 757429     /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
b77fd000-b77fe000 r--p 0001a000 08:01 757429     /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
b77fe000-b77ff000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 757429     /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
bff30000-bff45000 rw-p bffea000 00:00 0          [stack]
53-Aborted (core dumped)
```

Values 1 to 51 are correct, value 52 doesn't exist and 53 should not be displayed.

Comment: If you build with debug-information (`-g` option to GCC) then you will be able to see *which line* the crash happens it.

Comment: Oh, and you *do* initialize the stack (i.e. call `PILA_Crea`)?

Comment: In the function `PILA_Destrueix()` you need to change the free statement to: `free(*pP)`  You aren't using this function currently in the code you show and I don't see any other issues.

Comment: Your push and pop functions look correct, so I'm with @JoachimPileborg that it looks like it might be a missing initialization. If `PILA_Crea` weren't called, then the first element you push would link to an uninitialized pointer, and it looks like when you are unwinding the stack, you're getting to that first element and not seeing a NULL for next and walking off into the weeds.

Comment: @BradBudlong That seems like a likely culprit, you should add that as an answer.